# Organizing a MS Visual Studio 2013 Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a game in SFML, but I wanted to use .tmx files for the maps, so I added those necessary files to my project, and subsequently had to add Box2D and zlib to my project so that everything compiled ok.  Now that everything compiled ok, I can't help but notice how much of the code in my project doesn't actually pertain to what I'm working on.  It's mostly the code from zlib, and the tmx map loader.  It looks like this:

[image: Solution Explorer]

With the only code that's mine being in the Include filter, and the code that isn't in any filter but Source.

So ultimately my question is this.  Is there a way that I can have all of those header files and cpp files that don't directly pertain to my game in another project in the solution that I can somehow reference?  I guess I just want to clean up the project and make it easier to navigate, but I don't know enough about Visual Studio.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of having non-project related files not included in your project is called "linking" and is one of the core concepts of C++.

Just build zlib, the TMX loader and pugixml as libraries and link against them. That way you'll have no library code in your project solution and things are logically and physically separated.

Comment: Yeah, that seems much more logical. Thanks for the help!